# control multiple devices via USB in python ? possible ?

Tags: python

I would like to  run separately some test on devices  which are connected to HUB USB. My problem is that I don't know how to identify each device when I use the function `usb.core.find`. Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

An example of a loop to list connected USB devices from [here](http://www.orangecoat.com/how-to/use-pyusb-to-find-vendor-and-product-ids-for-usb-devices).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import usb.core
# find USB devices
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
# loop through devices, printing vendor and product ids in decimal and hex
for cfg in dev:
  sys.stdout.write('Decimal VendorID=' + str(cfg.idVendor) + ' & ProductID=' +     str(cfg.idProduct) + '\n')
  sys.stdout.write('Hexadecimal VendorID=' + hex(cfg.idVendor) + ' & ProductID=' + hex(cfg.idProduct) + '\n\n'
```

[PyUSB Documentation Link](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html)

[PyUSB Sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyusb/)

Comment: This only works if the device has the attributes set to your naming convention, in my case did not work, but the answer as a whole can be extrapolated